# What does "in no time" mean?

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

What does the following sentence mean?

> The trip can be made in no time.

Comment: It's a hyperbolic way of saying it's a short trip.

Comment: *in no time* is used to mean *very quickly*. Senescence is the process of growing old: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/senescence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"in no time" = "[almost] immediately"

Comment: Hello Max. I'm sure that the reason Robusto didn't post an 'answer' was that he didn't consider the question suitable for ELU. ELU is intended for serious language enthusiasts ... well, I'm sure you've read the stuff in the Help Center. The questioner could just have looked up the meaning.

Comment: I didn't ask that offtopic question, why -1 my answer?

Comment: It wasn't my downvote. I might well have downvoted someone with a million rep points for this answer, though. As FumbleFingers  has said: … we should seek to discourage people from providing trivial answers to trivial questions ... We all like to be helpful, but the place for that level of help is English Language Learners –

Comment: I agree that purity should be maintained, but would not it be more reasonable to seek some kind of 'discouragement' just by deleting useless questions to prevent useless answers (thus reducing the entropy), instead of introducing some kind of "flogging" (btw, is this word usage correct?) system?

(Sorry for my English, I'm working on it).

Comment: It _has_ been closed as general reference. But I agree with FF that 'we should seek to discourage people from providing trivial answers to trivial questions', as well as discouraging the questions themselves.

Answer (score 2):

> **[in no time](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/time_1)** : very quickly or very soon:
>
> - The children ate their dinner in no time.

The trip can be made *in no time/very quickly.*

The language used is figurative, an exaggerated form (and as @Robusto states-hyperbolic)

Comment: I'm sure that the reason Robusto didn't post an 'answer' was that he didn't consider the question suitable for ELU.